# "Too few positionals passed" in arg-less method with type captures

Tags: raku

In this script:

```
role Capturer {
    method capturing(::CLASS:D: $ ) {
        say "Working with ", $?CLASS, " that holds ", $.gist;
    }
}


( <1 2 3 4> but Capturer ).capturing();
```

A arg-less method is defined, `capturing`, but if I call it this way, I get:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
  in method capturing at captured-class.p6 line 4
  in block <unit> at captured-class.p6 line 10
```

I can fix that giving it a dummy argument

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1
  in method capturing at captured-class.p6 line 4
  in block <unit> at captured-class.p6 line 10
```

Which then returns:

```
Working with (List+{Capturer}) that holds (1 2 3 4)
```

Any idea of what kind of argument is waiting for there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any argument really, because the method you defined is **NOT** argumentless:

```
method capturing(::CLASS:D: $ )
                           ^^^
```

that defines a single, nameless positional argument.  Which, without any type specification, will accept an `Any`.  So the answer to your question:

> Any idea of what kind of argument is waiting for there?

already contains the answer: `Any` value  :-)

Comment: @jjmerelo I also used to get confused with the colons in heavely-typed signatures with named parameters. One way to deal with it is by not trying to register them
separately but as the units they're associating with. For example,
`::?CLASS` is a unit and there's no point trying to register the colons separately
in it. Then, `:D` is added to that previous unit. Finally we've `:` to separate
the invocant from the regular parameters.